# Java ServerSocket not receiving HTTP response - timeout

Tags: java

I am writing a prototype for a simple client-server program.  The client issues an HTTP PUT request (working successfully),but it is not receiving an HTTP response and is timing out.  I have been playing around with the code and experimenting with InputStream and OutputStream for hours but I'm missing something. Probably something simple, as I haven't done much coding in Java.

Client Code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://" + remoteFilepath);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setReadTimeout(5000);
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        //httpCon.setDoInput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            httpCon.getOutputStream());
        String tmp = getContent(localFilepath);
        System.out.println("tmp: " + tmp);
        out.write(tmp + "\n"); 
        out.flush();
        httpCon.connect();
        System.out.println("before afterClient");
        BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
        System.out.println("after fromClient");
        String line;
        while ((line = fromClient.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        System.out.println("response code: " + httpCon.getResponseCode() + ", response message: " + httpCon.getResponseMessage());
```

Server Code: inside run method

```
BufferedReader fromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
if(line.startsWith("PUT")){
                    methodLine = line.split(" ");
                    this.put(fromClient, line, methodLine);
}
```

put() method - contains http response

```
public void put(BufferedReader fromClient, String line, String[] putLine){
        String[] contentLine;

        try{
        while((line = fromClient.readLine()) != null){
            if(line.startsWith("Content-Length:")){
                contentLine = line.split(" ");
                //get the content, then send back HTTP response
                int numChars = Integer.parseInt(contentLine[1]);
                char[] cbuf = new char[numChars]; 
                fromClient.readLine(); //skip over blank line
                fromClient.read(cbuf);  //read the specified number of bytes

                System.out.println("cbuf" + new String(cbuf));

                //store <file,content> in memory

                contentMap.put(putLine[1], new String(cbuf));

                //send back HTTP response then break
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                        conn.getOutputStream());
                out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK" + "\n");  //response 
                out.flush();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try that with two "\n" in the HTTP response... (to indicate no headers)

Comment: That seemed to help. It now appears to be blocking on fromClient.readLine().

Comment: ServerSockets don't receive anything, and servers don't receive responses, they send them. Please straighten this out.

Comment: @onon15 The line terminator in HTTP is \r\n, not \n.

Comment: `ServerSockets` don't receive anything, and servers send responses, not receive them.

Answer (score -1):

eh, you can write this in your response, and then I use **PostMan** to test it , that show me what I want to see.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
COntent-Length: your length
```